# Trying to upload files using springs. Getting file count as 1. even I submit the form with no file choosen

Tags: java, spring-mvc, apache-commons-fileupload

Am trying to upload files using springs.
working on bulk files upload.
I need files count as 0 when I submit the form without choosing a file.
Here is my code:
My controller as follows:

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/uploadMultipleFilesMA",method=RequestMethod.POST)
  public String handleFileUploadMA(@ModelAttribute("multipleFileUploadForm") 
  MultipleFileUploadForm multipleFileUploadForm, Model model)
  {

   List<MultipartFile> files=multipleFileUploadForm.getFiles(); 
   all Multipart files in a List

   System.out.println(" Files count " + files.size());
   model.addAttribute("files", files);
   return "result";
  }
```

and Bean class as follows :

```
  public class MultipleFileUploadForm {

    private List<MultipartFile> files;

    public List<MultipartFile> getFiles() {
        return files;
    }

    public void setFiles(List<MultipartFile> files) {
        this.files = files;
    } 
}
```

My Jsp Looks Like :

```
 <form:form method="post" action="uploadMultipleFilesMA.do"  
 modelAttribute="multipleFileUploadForm"   enctype="multipart/form-data">
<TABLE id="fuTable"  border="1">
<TR>
    <TD> <input name="files[0]" type="file"></TD>
</TR>

</TABLE>
<br>    <input  type="button" value="Add More File"  
 onclick="AddMoreFile('fuTable')">
<input type="submit" value="Upload">

 </form:form>
```

Comment: no need to specifiy index in  input type `<input name="files" type="file">`

Comment: even though getting same count 1

Comment: you can try <input name="files" type="file"  multiple="multiple">

Comment: you are using `<form:form> ` at initially only one will be available while adding it javascript it wont get effect that it may be the problem for you

Comment: thanks I have changed and tried,but same count

Comment: when i print multipleFileUploadForm i get this :net.javaonline.spring.fileupload.form.MultipleFileUploadForm@6818a4b9

Comment: `@ModelAttribute("multipleFileUploadForm") 
  MultipleFileUploadForm multipleFileUploadForm` instead of this try @RequestParam `List<MultipartFile> files`

Comment: If is use @Requestparam it is mandatory to upload a file.but I have to submit other text files along with this file to the same controller

Comment: that's not a problem  `@RequestParam(required=false) List<MultipartFile> files`

Comment: Tried but same count

Comment: i thought you have missed something else

Comment: what else could I have missed?